# cryptography.Fernet why does decrypt still work on modified token

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

I am a new user of py-cryptography. I am finding that even the encrypted token is modified at end, it still decrypts OK. How so?

Here is a test script

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
f = Fernet( Fernet.generate_key() )
word = b"very secret thing"
print("encrypting...", word)
token = f.encrypt( word )
print("decrypting...", len(token), token,)
reword = f.decrypt( token )
print("works as expected" if reword == word else "oops!")

modtoken = str.encode( token.decode() + "?abcd." )
print("modified token, appended stuff")
print("decrypting...", len(modtoken), modtoken)
reword = f.decrypt( modtoken )
print("whoops! still decrypts ok" if reword == word else "good boy!")
```

and the  output was

```
encrypting... b'very secret thing'
decrypting... 120 b'gAAAAABb3TIJLCgbVdq-CgQ3V7V3eehQ02h_O70iZkCjd6KCU9GsErog-c-LluWITQg5lTsp5ldoTc0J_XdFCd-jhoJPOYAKyQbzbHDJZKTGORIJSflO1do='
works as expected
modified token, appended stuff
decrypting... 126 b'gAAAAABb3TIJLCgbVdq-CgQ3V7V3eehQ02h_O70iZkCjd6KCU9GsErog-c-LluWITQg5lTsp5ldoTc0J_XdFCd-jhoJPOYAKyQbzbHDJZKTGORIJSflO1do=?abcd.'
whoops! still decrypts ok
```

Is this expected behavior? If so, how do I check if the token is not modified between encrypt and decrypt?

python 3.6.6 on ubuntu under WSL
cryptography - github.com/pyca/cryptography

---EDIT---

I changed the line

```
word = b"very secret thing"
```

to

```
word = b"very secret thing XXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

and the effect was (1) the token length went from 120 to 140 (2) decrypting modtoken raised an Exception!

After reading Paul's answer I also am wondering if it would be wise to use this library in production code or if someone could suggest a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an artifact of the malleability of base64 with Python's decoder. When the fernet token is base64 decoded everything you've added is discarded. This means that when the HMAC value is checked the ciphertext is untampered and the token passes.

While this is not directly a problem, it could **become** a problem if a user does something unwise with presumed token uniqueness. To be clear, Fernet has strong integrity guarantees for the token payload, but the base64 itself has limited malleability.

Over 3 years ago I tried to get the Fernet spec updated to require strict base64 encoding (https://github.com/fernet/spec/pull/11) but unfortunately the authors are not maintaining their spec and nothing has happened. We don't want to break compatibility with other Fernet implementations and this issue, while annoying, isn't enough to convince me that we need to fork it at this time.

Comment: I modified the original string length, and now I get an exception when decoding. It looks like if the encrypted token length is > 120 then it raises. That's funny. Also, if authors are not maintaining their spec, then is it wise to use this library, is there an alternative?

Comment: I am not marking this as answer as I am still seeking a robust tool

Comment: I don't believe the perceived malleability here is a large issue, hence why we haven't forked. Fernet tokens offer strong integrity and authenticity guarantees. The only issue is that the default encoding means that multiple "base64-like" payloads can map to the same ciphertext + HMAC value, i.e. a surjective mapping.

Comment: Does that mean that the fernet generated token can only be tweaked on right-end only (but not in the middle or the left) for this weakness? That would be an acceptable weakness as the "core" of the token is held strong. Is that how you are using "surjective" here?

Comment: You can add anything that the base64 decoder will ignore. In Python this is anything after the padding, but also any invalid base64 chars to the left. The point is that the "token" is not the characters you see, it is the decoded value. The decoded value is strongly authenticated and cannot be mutated in any way without failing. You can think of the encoded token as a domain that maps to the domain of actual tokens. It is called surjective because (due to the b64 decoder laxness) more than one "b64" token can map to a single decoded value. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function